# Python, Get status from running command

Tags: python-2.7, popen

I am running my own script to launch HandBrakeCLI. HandBrake takes a few hours to do it's job.

I intend to launch this script from cron, so there will be no real output from the script (I can update a file from time to time.)

HandBrake can tell me what it is doing at the bottom line of the terminal while it is running.

I am using Popen to launch handbrake.

How can I look at the output of handbrake while it is running to glean it's status in real (well near real) time?

Here is the command I am using:

```
command = ['HandBrakeCLI', '-i', long_source, '-o', long_target, '-f', 'mp4'] # + a bunch more
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print out
print err
```

This works, but I want output from `Popen` during execution, not wait till after it is done.

Thanks, Mark.

PS. Ubuntu server 12.04

Comment: What have you tried?  It seems to me that `subprocess.Popen` would be exactly the right approach, so without seeing an error message I don't know why you wouldn't be able to do this.

Comment: Here is the command I am using:  `p = subprocess.Popen(['HandBrakeCLI', '-i', long_source, '-o', long_target, '-f', 'mp4'..a bunch more ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`
  `out, err = p.communicate()`
  `print out`
  `print err`

Comment: This works, but I want output from Popen **during** execution, not wait till after it is done.  Formatting in this comment section doesn't work.

Comment: don't put the code into the comments, [edit] your question instead.

Comment: What happens if you drop `stdout=PIPE` and `stderr=PIPE` and `tail -F` the file where your Python process output goes?

Answer (score 0):

You can direct output of cron to some file and refer that file.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `.communicate()` you can just start the subprocess using `Popen()` and thereafter periodically check its `stdout` and `stderr` line by line:

```
sp = subprocess.Popen( command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE )

# later....
while continueMyEventLoop:
    out = sp.stdout.readline()
    err = sp.stderr.readline()

    DealWith( out, err )
    DoOtherStuff()
```